# Using Gson instead of Jackson in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, gson, spring-webflux

We have many Spring MVC projects already, which all use gson instead of jackson for response body encode. Our bean classes are all written based on gson annotation. Now I am setting up a Spring Webflux restful server. It would save a lot of work if we can use the old bean classes from our Spring MVC projects.

I have tried `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson` property to no avail.

I have tried `HttpMessageConverter` bean, which is included in webflux packages, but that does not work as in the Spring MVC projects.

I googled a lot and the only thing helpful is to implement `org.springframework.http.codec.HttpMessageEncoder` class and set it to `WebFluxConfigurer.configureHttpMessageCodecs()` method:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.customCodecs().decoder(new GsonHttpMessageDecoder());
        configurer.customCodecs().encoder(new GsonHttpMessageEncoder());
    }

    private static class GsonHttpMessageEncoder implements HttpMessageEncoder {
        ...
    }

    private static class GsonHttpMessageDecoder implements HttpMessageDecoder {
        ...
    }
}
```

I haven't try this out yet, since it is a little complex. Is there some easy way to replace jackson with gson in Spring Webflux?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but have you tried excluding the transitive Jackson dependency? That might force WebFlux to use the configuration you've provided (GSON).

Comment: why would one use gson over jackson?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Because we already have many beans written with gson annotation like `@Expose` `@SerializedName` in SpringMVC projects, and these beans are shared across our projects by a jar as a common api definition between services. If we use jackson, we must rewrite these beans and logic along with them. I think it is not a good practice to have two code implementation represent one fact, since it violates Single-Point-of-Truth rule.
Apart from that, no big deal indeed. If solving the problem cost too much, I will surrender and use jackson~.

Comment: looks like WebConfiguration  is the only way to go. webflux does not support gson out of box.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf - One reason would be that Gson is a better platform for highly customized serialization of generic types. Jackson is battle-hardened and widely-used, but its design is incoherent when it comes to handling generic types.

Comment: @Dorados which is a highly subjective opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Framework doesn't support GSON as a WebFlux `Encoder` / `Decoder` for now. Feel free to [follow up on the dedicated issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27131).

Note that as far as I know, GSON doesn't support non-blocking parsing so even if the support is implemented in Framework, it won't be complete and should not cover streaming input use cases.